# jquery timeline

Tags: jquery, slide, timeline

I need to create a timeline module similar to the one on the following site
the top of the page displays a slide with a timeline function
Is there a ready to use jquery plugin to do this?

Here's [the link](http://global.burton.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Burton_GLOBAL-Site/default/Team-Rider?rid=shaun-white)

Comment: Do you mean "I want an image to display full screen"? There is no "slide" on that site, from what I understand in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQueryUI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) with custom styles.
If you want to change an image you do it with the change event